# Topology - Term for the Part of a Boundary which is Part of a Set.

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Consider the half open interval $(0, 1]$ in $R$. Its boundary is the set {$0, 1$}, of which $1 \in (0, 1]$ and $0 \not \in (0, 1]$

Similarly the half disk in X-Y defined by {$y \ge 0$  and $x^2 + y^2 < 1$} includes the boundary points in  $[(-1, 0), (1, 0)]$ but not those {$y > 0$  and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$}.

**Is there a term specifically identifying the part of a boundary which is included in a set** ?

Comment: I don't think there is a special term for such a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard of one, but you could always make up one, for example *boundary points **in** $A$*.

Another possibility comes from the second characterization of such points:
$$\partial A\cap A=A\setminus A^\circ.$$
This last equality suggests a swift formulation, with which one avoids introducing new terminology: *non-interior points of $A$*.

Comment: "non-interior points" sounds good to me.

Comment: I am glad you like it.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Done.